# How to code html email to print out two separate pages?

Tags: html, html-email, business-catalyst

A Business Catalyst ecommerce drop shipping order gets sent to the vendor. I want to add a second table that is the Packing Slip the vendor will use when shipping the product to my customer.

Customizing html email that contains two tables.
1. Vendor Drop Shipping Order
2. Vendor Packing Slip

Trying to figure out how to separate the two tables so they will print as two separate pages when recipient get the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know BC and how its system emails work. In this case you would not be able to generate an attached PDF. (Unless you were to use a third party service that would take an email, convert it to PDF, then email the PDF. I am not aware of any such service off the top of my head.) Here is what you *can* do.

Start by customizing the Drop Shipping Email. You see the invoice form by default. Create another table that contains the packing slip information. (For a list of tags for the email, see [this documentation](http://docs.businesscatalyst.com/dev-assets/reference#!/tag-reference/system-emails/drop-shipping-email.html).)

You then can add styles that when the person prints the page it breaks the email into two pages. For example:

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
    /* NOTE: This style tag can go anywhere in the email. */
    @media print {
        .page-break {page-break-after: always;}
    }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- Code of Invoice -->

<div class="page-break">&nbsp;</div>

<!-- Code of Packing Slip -->
```

When this is printed, it should break the top of the email (anything before `<div class="page-break">&nbsp;</div>`) into one page, and the rest into a second. **However**, support for `@media print` is not very good in email clients, so unfortunately, this won't work in many email clients. You can read [this article](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2010/09/how-do-i-create-a-printer-friendly-email-newsletter/) on `@media print` in email.

If you know your drop shipper does you one of the email clients that supports `@media print` in email then give it a try, otherwise ou do have two other options available:

1. Take the information and manually send it to the drop shipper.
2. Have the drop shipper print one page and then cut the page in half.

(I know neither are ideal.)

Answer (score 2):

Two reasons why that won't probably work:

1. Most email clients clean your HTML and CSS before displaying it. This process differs very much from client to client (that's why most newsletters are full of images).
2. The CSS property that tells the browser to break the page doesn't work for some browsers (e.g. Google Chrome). See [this bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5097) in webkit for more information.

Anyway, this is what you should add to the last HTML tag you want in the first page:

```
style="page-break-after: always;"
```

However, I **strongly** recommend that you try to generate a PDF file or something like that to be sent as an attachment.

Comment: I'd go with sending an attachment as suggested in this answer. Far more control of the contents (spacing/pages etc..) which will be consistent wherever it is emailed or opened. Consider using HTML to PDF conversion, where you use HTML and CSS to generate your content/pages as you want them using the 'page-break-after: always;'

Comment: @Steven, do you have any HTML to PDF tools to recommend? That would be useful for me too. :)

Comment: There are so many out there and I'm sure there are many that can do the job. I would start off with googling 'html to pdf api' to compare pricing and features then you can make your own informed decision :)